# Memory leaks, bitmaps, fragments

Tags: android, android-memory

I have an activity that hosts a fragment with Gallery inside it. When I start another activity , essentially, I want to free the memory filled with gallery bitmaps.

My fragment is inserted dynamically like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();

    if (_promoFragment == null) {
        _promoFragment = new TabletPromoFragment();
    }

    fragmentTransaction.replace(_singlePageContainerId, _promoFragment);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I even call  _promoFragment.onDestroyView in onPause of the activity, but MAT still shows me that there's a Gallery object that holds those references to Bitmaps.

What can you suggest ?

p.s. I can post MAT report if it is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You are having problems with references and **objects clinging on to memory way past the lifecycle of your fragments & activities.**

[Check out my reply on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592211/memory-not-freeing-after-fragment-is-removed/38595895#38595895)

**You have to ensure no reference is left behind whenever you destroy a fragment/activity**. Make sure to clear all its usage and history so Android's Garbage Collector successfully processes it

Answer (score 0):

Use weak references for Bitmaps. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html

Comment: I've already used - I'm using https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/blob/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/ImageLoader.java to show bitmaps acyncroniously. I have a doubt about this line:   private Map<String, Bitmap> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true)); However I think my problem is that fragments view doesn;t get destryed when I leave the first activity