# Android Memory Management issues

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, leakcanary

I'm working on my first android application which is a big application though.. I have completed half of my app but what makes me worry is that the memory used by app.. Initially I faced the issues regarding out of memory exceptions.. I first started analyzing my app with MAT(Memory Analyzer Tool) of Android Studio, which was very difficult to track the memory usage.. My app would reach allocated space of 96mb and crash.. Then After Reading on internet i used Leak Canary which pointed out the static resources that was eating memory.. and now my app regularly gets Garbage collected but still i find the allocated space remains to be around 70 mb, Like my app starts with allocation of 30mb when i use app for about 2 min and come back to initial screen the allocated space is not same as initial... For beginners like me it is hard to track the memory usage to the core using MAT and is there a best approach or tool which would give me a clear picture of allocated space by objects.. Objects that are taking maximum space.. objects that are supposed get destroyed but not destroyed?? and retaining Image memory etc etc Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been a few posts here related to memory management.

We have all been newbies at some point and thankfully experience and problems like these have proven to be excellent 'teachers'.
Like I have said in another post :

> This will of course cause memory problems such as leaks, OOM and
>   unnecessary resource binding. **There is absolutely no automatic way to
>   free up memory.** You can not, under any circumstances, rely solely on
>   the Garbage Collector

Basically, you must ensure that you allocate **only the required resources** and deallocate them as soon as you know you wont need them anymore within the Lifecyce

I have wrote a more detailed explanation with code (that you can implement on your project) to deal with your memory issues which can be found here :

[It can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592211/memory-not-freeing-after-fragment-is-removed/38595895#38595895)

Regards,

Comment: i went through your answer...  That would definitely help me to clear up  some memory... Ty

Answer (score 1):

One of the main 'memory leakers' is the Bitmap. Sometimes when you load an image in a a View, it uses a lot of memory in the action. I used to recommend using libraries like Glide or Fresco which are better handling memory issues and have a lot of common features already implemented.

Also you could try to free resources for each activity in your onDestroy method.

Nevertheless, I would be great if you could give us a deeper overview of your project.

Regards.

Comment: My application is a like a shopping app.. and i'm using a single activity and rest all are fragments.. I ll try the suggested libraries.. pls lemme know if you think anything useful that would help me overcome the memory issues..

Comment: Check Ricardo Vieira answer and this tutorial which could be useful to you.
https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/03/wrangling-dalvik-memory-management-in-android-part-1-of-2/

Comment: Yeah i ll go through all the  links and try to optimize my app to the best i can... Thank you for all links n references..